# How with pivot relation set additive filter?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 9 app I  use many to many relation with table article_vote joining 2 tables :

```
return new class extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreignId('vote_id')->references('id')->on('votes')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');

            ...
            
        });

    }
```

In app/Models/Article.php model I have relation :

```
public function onlyActiveVotes(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Vote::class, 'article_vote', 'article_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->wherePivot('active', true)
        ->withPivot(['active', 'expired_at', 'supervisor_id', 'supervisor_notes']);
}
```

and I want having Article by Id($id)

```
$article      = Article::getById($id)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Using onlyActiveVotes relation to get filtered data from vote :

```
$voteTableName = ((new Vote)->getTable());
$articleVotes = $article->onlyActiveVotes()::whereHas('votes', function ($query) use($request, $voteTableName)   {
    $query->where($voteTableName . '.vote_category_id', $request->filter_vote_vote_category_id);
})->get();
```

It does not work, as I got error :

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::whereHas does not exist. i
```

Line below returns collection

```
dd($article->onlyActiveVotes );
```

Line below returns BelongsToMany:

```
dd($article->onlyActiveVotes() );


Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#2283 // app/Repositories/ArticleToManyVotesRepository.php:74
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#2218
    #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#2268
```

On

```
dd($article->onlyActiveVotes()->query );
```

I got error:

```
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$query
```

If there is a way to use whereHas with onlyActiveVotes relation ?

**Updated BLOCK :**

I hope I clearly exoplaned what I want :  want to get only filtered votes which arerelated with pivot through $article model

Aftet I fixed :

```
$filteredArticleVotes = $article->onlyActiveVotes()->whereHas
```

I got other error :

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\Vote::onlyActiveVotes()
```

pointing at line

```
$filteredArticleVotes = $article->onlyActiveVotes()->whereHas('onlyActiveVotes', function ($query) use($request, $voteTableName)   {
    $query->where($voteTableName . '.vote_category_id', $request->filter_vote_vote_category_id);
})->get();
```

As I wrote in my post Article model has onlyActiveVotes method and I expected the code above have to work, but it did not...

Thanks!

Comment: it should be like this : `$article->onlyActiveVotes()->whereHas`

Comment: also could you explain 
```
$voteTableName = ((new Vote)->getTable());
$articleVotes = $article->onlyActiveVotes()::whereHas('votes', function ($query) use($request, $voteTableName)   {
    $query->where($voteTableName . '.vote_category_id', $request->filter_vote_vote_category_id);
})->get();
```
what kind of result do you want? this code is wrong. and I can help you if you told me what is your desire output.

Comment: I want to get only filtered votes which arerelated with pivot through $article model

Comment: Please take look at Updated BLOCK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onlyActiveVotes()` already returns a query builder for the votes table, you can directly chain the `where()` method to filter the results by the `vote_category_id` column. The `whereHas()` method is not necessary in this case.

```
$articleVotes = $article->onlyActiveVotes()
    ->where('vote_category_id', $request->filter_vote_vote_category_id)
    ->get();
```